# Attaching automation test results to slack message

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, automation, automated-tests, slack-api

I am currently running my automation (UI & API) tests on azure devops release pipeline.
Whenever the test run finishes I get a notification to my slack:

[image: 1]

Now theres only one way to view the test results after a run:
You can click on the Release hotlink and you will get redirected to the full release run info and test results too
[image].
Now my question is: is it possible to somehow customize the release notes?
For example Id love to attach Test Results to the slack message. Something along the lines:

```
TestResults:
Passed: 13
Failed: 2
```

Or somehow attach the .trx/.html file that gets generated after the test run. So I could easily view the results without clicking on the release hotlink.

Maybe its possible to extract test results using GET Runs List API method?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the result file(eg:trx) with a powershell script, get the testrun details,  post to slack channel via [rest api](https://api.slack.com/messaging/sending#publishing) or [PostSlackNotification](https://github.com/kasunkv/slack-notification) task.

For example: check the trx file in log:
[image: trx file for log screenshot]

Add a new powershell script task to parse testrun details:

```
#get the path of the trx file from the output folder.
$path = Get-ChildItem -Path $(Agent.TempDirectory)\TestResults -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Filter *.trx |  Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq '.trx' }

$appConfigFile = $path.FullName  #path to test result trx file 

$appConfig = New-Object XML 
$appConfig.Load($appConfigFile) 
$testsummary = $appConfig.DocumentElement.ResultSummary.Counters | select total, passed, failed, aborted

echo $testsummary   # check testsummary

echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testSummary]$($testsummary)" #set the testsummary to environment variable
```

Get the testrun result as below:
[image: testrun summary screenshot]

Posted to slack channel:

[image: slack result]

Answer (score 1):

There is an npm package to publish test results back to either microsoft teams or slack.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/test-results-reporter

You need to create an incoming-webhook and a simple config file to get started.

Add the below command in your pipeline yaml file.

```
- script: npx test-results-reporter publish -c config.json
```