# How to retrieve the number of passed, failed unit-tests of a pipeline-job from AzureDevops using a script

Tags: azure, unit-testing, azure-devops, pipeline

After completing a pipeline job, I have the option to access the "Tests" section within the pipeline job details. Within this section, I can view the count of tests categorized as "passed," "failed," and "other."

My objective is to create a script that retrieves these counts. To achieve this, I've attempted to use the following endpoint:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{ORGANIZATION}/{PROJECT}/_apis/test/runs/{runId}/results?api-version=6.1-preview.6
```

However, when I sum the numbers for the outcomes labeled as "passed," "failed," and "other," the total does not match the counts displayed in the Azure DevOps user interface.

I'm uncertain if I'm using the correct endpoint or if there's an alternative method to retrieve these test counts.

Comment: Is there more than one test project in the build? You may need to use the [Runs - Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/query?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2) endpoint to get the runs for the `buildId`. Then use the [Results - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP) endpoint for each `runId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **run outcome** should be identical with the **Tests** tab on pipeline result page. Check if there could more than one runs in the tests(2 runs in sample screenshot below).
[image]

To count the test outcome, the rest api [Runs - Get Test Run Statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/get-test-run-statistics?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) could be better, it shows the **count** for **each run** directly.

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{runId}/Statistics?api-version=7.1-preview.3`

[image]

Another option is to parse the test result file, you can find my answer in link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68826981/14996050).