Azure Pipeline Results on a Confluence Page
We've set up several Azure Pipelines that run automatically every night,
and we're using Azure dashboards to view the results.
Is there a way to display the number of test cases run, passed, and failed in these pipelines on a Confluence page?
Could you let me know if there's a Confluence Macro or Gadget that can fetch results from Azure Pipelines and display them as charts, Pie Charts or fancy formats in Confluence?
Please advise.

Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77303160/how-to-retrieve-the-number-of-passed-failed-unit-tests-of-a-pipeline-job-from-a helpful?

Looks good, but can this be used to publish results on a confluence page ?
